# Why would push in solidity only push once?

Tags: solidity

I have the code which follows. It adds the hashes into contracts fine but the my myHashes array gets just one value at 0. Is there any reason why this push would fail?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;



contract RegisterContract {

    uint public contractWeight;

    mapping(bytes32=>string) public contracts;
    bytes32[] public myHashes;

    function addContract ( string jsonInput, bytes32 hashKey) public {
        contracts[hashKey] = jsonInput;
        myHashes.push(hashKey);
     }

    function addWeight (uint weight) public {
        contractWeight = weight;
    }

    function () payable public {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you mean "one value at 0"? That it's just of length of 1, or that there is one value which is 0 in your array?

Comment: Can you give the data you used?

Comment: I did more testing it seems the smart contract is correct but the json string has quotes in it and that is causes the function to stop working.

Comment: @TrevorOakley Storing files on blockchain is not a perfect solution. Have you considered storing the hash of the file in the blockchain and keeping the file on IPFS. E.g. https://medium.com/@mycoralhealth/learn-to-securely-share-files-on-the-blockchain-with-ipfs-219ee47df54c

Comment: Yes I have of course. But someone else is controlling the design and he wants to store strings.